# Can't make jquery validation work using rules, messages method

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I can't figure out why form2 fails validation but form1 passes validation (using jQuery validation plugin).  How can I make form1 fail validation as well using the code below?

**HTML**

```
<form id="form1" method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" id="viewName1">
     <h3></h3>
</form>

<form id="form2" method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" id="viewName2" required>
     <h3></h3>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#form1').validate({
    rules: {
        viewName: 'required'
    },
    messages: {
        viewName: '* view name is required'
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
        $('#form1 h3').text('Form1 valid');
    },
    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
        $('#form1 h3').text('Form1 invalid');
    }
});
$('#form1').submit();

$('#form2').validate({
    submitHandler: function () {
        $('#form1 h3').text('Form1 valid');
    },
    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
        $('#form1 h3').text('Form1 invalid');
    }
});
$('#form2').submit();
```

**FIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/5xFhA/4/

Comment: Please don't edit the corrected code into your question.  The question and answer already speak for themselves.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because your input elements do not have a `name` attribute.  This is a requirement of the plugin.

[See the "markup recommendations" section of the docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/):

> *"The `name` attribute is 'required' for input elements, the
>   validation plugin doesn't work without it."*

```
$('#form1').validate({
    rules: {
        viewName: 'required' // <-- "viewName" is the 'name' attribute, not id
    },
    messages: {
        viewName: '* view name is required'  // <-- "viewName" is the 'name' attribute, not id
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
        $('#form1 h3').text('Form1 valid');
    },
    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
        $('#form1 h3').text('Form1 invalid');
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/5xFhA/10/**